# Why does Excel inconsistently manage the cut rows range during a cut and paste to a new sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have identified an inconsistency in the source range address for cut cells.

I have a utility in an Excel-based tool that migrates rows that the user selects. The user then must select the destination, which can be on the same sheet or on a different sheet.

The issue of Excel leaving blank lines when cutting and inserting into a different sheet are well known (c.f. [Cutting Row with Data and moving to different sheet VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131874/cutting-row-with-data-and-moving-to-different-sheet-vba) and [Excel VBA remove blank row after cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440947/excel-vba-remove-blank-row-after-cut)) and they have solutions for addressing it. However, my tool uses a different approach (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27093382/9101981) - which I will now show does not work as intended.

```
Sub TestMigration()
''    Source Cells = migrateSource.Range("A3:A4") ' this simulates how the ranges are selected in the real world application
''    Target Cells = migrateTarget.Range("A7") ' this simulates the real world application where this is chosen through a pick box
    MigrateRows migrateSource.Range("A3:A4"), migrateTarget.Range("A7")
End Sub

Sub MigrateRows(sourceCells As Range, targetCells As Range)
                Debug.Print "Original source address: " & sourceCells.Worksheet.Name & "," & sourceCells.Address
    sourceCells.EntireRow.Cut ' the command used in the real world application
                Debug.Print "After cut source address: " & sourceCells.Worksheet.Name & "," & sourceCells.Address
    targetCells.Insert
                Debug.Print "After insert source address: " & sourceCells.Worksheet.Name & "," & sourceCells.Address
    If Not (sourceCells.Worksheet Is targetCells.Worksheet) Then sourceCells.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

The source and target data is:

[image: Source data][image: Target data]

The expected results are:

[image: Expected source data after cut and insert][image: Expected target data after cut and insert]

> Original source address: MigrateSource,$A$3:$A$4
>
> After cut source address: MigrateSource,$A$3:$A$4
>
> After insert source address: MigrateSource,$A$3:$A$4

The actual results are:

[image][image]

> Original source address: MigrateSource,$A$3:$A$4
>
> After cut source address: MigrateSource,$A$3:$A$4
>
> After insert source address: MigrateSource,$A$7:$A$8

The data above shows that the **source** range has taken on address of the inserted cells, but **not** the worksheet name. If the cut cells address were to "move", I would expect it to also take on the new worksheet.

### Additional information - what else did I try doing this?

1. I tried to create a copy of the source cells. As this is copying a reference, I did not expect it to work, and was not disappointed.

Code:

```
Sub MigrateRows1(sourceCells As Range, targetCells As Range)
Dim tSourceRowsCopy As Range
    Set tSourceRowsCopy = sourceCells
            Debug.Print "Original source address: " & sourceCells.Worksheet.Name & "," & sourceCells.Address
    sourceCells.EntireRow.Cut ' the command used in the real world application
            Debug.Print "After cut source address: " & sourceCells.Worksheet.Name & "," & sourceCells.Address
            Debug.Print "After cut source_copy address: " & tSourceRowsCopy.Worksheet.Name & "," & tSourceRowsCopy.Address
    targetCells.Insert
            Debug.Print "After insert source address: " & sourceCells.Worksheet.Name & "," & sourceCells.Address
            Debug.Print "After insert source_copy address: " & tSourceRowsCopy.Worksheet.Name & "," & tSourceRowsCopy.Address
    If Not (sourceCells.Worksheet Is targetCells.Worksheet) Then tSourceRowsCopy.EntireRow.Delete
            'Debug.Print "After delete source address: " & tSourceRows.Worksheet.Name & "," & tSourceRows.Address
            'Debug.Print "After delete source_copy address: " & tSourceRowsCopy.Worksheet.Name & "," & tSourceRowsCopy.Address
End Sub
```

> **Test Run 1 (MigrateRows1)**
>
> Original source address: MigrateSource,$A$3:$A$4
>
> After cut source address: MigrateSource,$A$3:$A$4
>
> After cut source_copy address: MigrateSource,$A$3:$A$4
>
> After insert source address: MigrateSource,$A$7:$A$8
>
> After insert source_copy address: MigrateSource,$A$7:$A$8
>
> *Outcome: No change*

2. I tried to create a new reference based on the address, but created this reference before the move.

Code:

```
Sub MigrateRows2(sourceCells As Range, targetCells As Range)
Dim tSourceRowsCopy As Range
Dim tSourceAddress As String
    tSourceAddress = sourceCells.Address
    Set tSourceRowsCopy = sourceCells.Worksheet.Range(tSourceAddress)
            Debug.Print "Original source address: " & sourceCells.Worksheet.Name & "," & sourceCells.Address
    sourceCells.EntireRow.Cut ' the command used in the real world application
            Debug.Print "After cut source address: " & sourceCells.Worksheet.Name & "," & sourceCells.Address
            Debug.Print "After cut source_copy address: " & tSourceRowsCopy.Worksheet.Name & "," & tSourceRowsCopy.Address
    targetCells.Insert
            Debug.Print "After insert source address: " & sourceCells.Worksheet.Name & "," & sourceCells.Address
            Debug.Print "After insert source_copy address: " & tSourceRowsCopy.Worksheet.Name & "," & tSourceRowsCopy.Address
    If Not (sourceCells.Worksheet Is targetCells.Worksheet) Then tSourceRowsCopy.Delete
        '    Debug.Print "After delete source address: " & tSourceRows.Worksheet.Name & "," & tSourceRows.Address
        '    Debug.Print "After delete source_copy address: " & tSourceRowsCopy.Worksheet.Name & "," & tSourceRowsCopy.Address
End Sub
```

> **Test Run 2 (MigrateRows2)**
>
> Original source address: MigrateSource,$A$3:$A$4
>
> After cut source address: MigrateSource,$A$3:$A$4
>
> After cut source_copy address: MigrateSource,$A$3:$A$4
>
> After insert source address: MigrateSource,$A$7:$A$8
>
> After insert source_copy address: MigrateSource,$A$7:$A$8
>
> *Outcome: No change*

3. I tried saving the address, and then creating a new reference just before the delete. This worked.

Code:

```
Sub MigrateRows3(sourceCells As Range, targetCells As Range)
Dim tSourceAddress As String
    tSourceAddress = sourceCells.Address
            Debug.Print "Original source address: " & sourceCells.Worksheet.Name & "," & sourceCells.Address
    sourceCells.EntireRow.Cut ' the command used in the real world application
            Debug.Print "After cut source address: " & sourceCells.Worksheet.Name & "," & sourceCells.Address
    targetCells.Insert
            Debug.Print "After insert source address: " & sourceCells.Worksheet.Name & "," & sourceCells.Address
            Debug.Print "Address to be deleted: " & sourceCells.Worksheet.Name & "," & tSourceAddress
    If Not (sourceCells.Worksheet Is targetCells.Worksheet) Then sourceCells.Worksheet.Range(tSourceAddress).Delete
            'Debug.Print "After delete source address: " & tSourceRows.Worksheet.Name & "," & tSourceRows.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: I was also interested in loosing named range reference and searched for good reading in vain. May refer my comment in SO [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408195/in-excel-vba-how-can-i-test-if-an-excel-range-object-variable-loses-its-referen#comment96190116_54408195)  also [link2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/named-range-losing-its-cell-reference-after/0649f50d-9a02-41dd-aad0-2d6329d837c8) terming it as expected excel behavior.

Comment: Not quite the same. As you can see, I am not trying to reference the deleted range (which rightly gives an error) - this is about an inconsistency in a range that is moved.